# In Sails express js what is the point of AJAX / AJAJ except for asynchronous processing?

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, express, sails.js

With a practical perspective what are the **pros and cons of AJAX** /AJAJ compared with other standards, such as html post followed by

```
res.render('returnView', {outputVariable: V })
```

Would it make any difference if processing the input takes very long time at the backend ?

**Is there any particular case where AJAJ would NOT be recommended ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a very big question. In short way it's a holy war about server-side vs client-side, so I'm only going to write several pros:

Server-side:

- User doesn't need to have JavaScript enabled on the browser. Nowadays it's a bit old manner, but sometimes when you deliver only information it's great.
- It is easier to maintain and error catching. You can catch on the server most of the problems
- Don't need additional code/application for monitoring errors on client side
- Better SEO optimization for Google and other bots

Client-side:

- Interactive pages - For instance, you might have a form that includes text inputs as well as an image upload/edit feature. Let's say the user writes some information on the text fields, then wants to upload/edit the photo without losing or submitting the information on the form fields. With AJAX / AJAJ you can have the user select the photo, crop, rotate, upload, you update the `<img>` element without reloading the page and losing the information in the forms.
- Smaller data are downloaded by client because html has same overhead as a xml
- Thiner server and cleaner API you can develop

More on topic you can read [here](http://tomdale.net/2015/02/youre-missing-the-point-of-server-side-rendered-javascript-apps/).